# Why do multi-stack visibly pushdown languages label each call/return with a particular stack?

Tags: automata-theory

In [A Unifying Approach for Multistack Pushdown Automata](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-44522-8_32), multistack visibly pushdown automata are defined in terms of an alphabet where each symbol is either a *call* or *return* for a particular stack or *internal*.

My question is, why is it necessary (or advantageous) to associate each call and return with a particular stack? Why is it not sufficient to label symbols with just call or return and let the same symbol push/pop from different stacks?